# How to access `JavaToolchainSpec` from within custom Gradle task

Tags: kotlin, gradle, plugins, configuration, toolchain

According to "[Toolchains for plugin authors](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/toolchains.html#sec:plugins)" it should be possible to access the configured [JavaToolchainSpec](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/jvm/toolchain/JavaToolchainSpec.html) from within a custom task. I try to use this approach within a custom plugin which creates a task based on the presence of the [JavaPlugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/plugins/JavaPlugin.html) and queries the configured `languageVersion` property. Here is a minimal example.

**build.gradle**

```
plugins {
  id 'application'
  id 'com.example.myplugin'
}

...

java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion.set(JavaLanguageVersion.of(17))
    }
}
```

**MyPlugin.kt**

```kotlin
class MyPlugin : Plugin<Project> {

  override fun apply(target: Project) {
    target.plugins.withType<JavaPlugin> {
      target.tasks.create<MyTask>("mytask")
    }
  }
}
```

**MyTask.kt**

```kotlin
abstract class MyTask : DefaultTask() {
  
  init {
    val extension = project.extensions.getByType<JavaPluginExtension>();
    val languageVersion = extension.toolchain.languageVersion.get();

    ...
  }
}
```

Once Gradle creates `MyTask` and the `languageVersion` property is queried, the build fails with the following error.

```
Cannot query the value of property 'languageVersion' because it has no value available.
```

My guess is that I am accessing the extension too early and it has not set its values at this time. My question now is if there is a way to wire up the configured properties (ideally with lazy mechanisms) with the task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apparently you have to configure the toolchain object in the java plugin extension to be able to use `JavaToolchainService`, using something like:

```
java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(11)
   }
}
```

if you don't do that Gradle will defaults to the current JVM and the whole toolchain API will be unavailable (leaving you with the error you reported)